# set video size in OSMF

Tags: actionscript-3, osmf

OSMV is very thick so so I'm trying to put a series of minimalist tutorials and again I'm stuck with something that should be dead simple.

I have a VideoElement that I added to a MediaPlayer.  Now now do I set the size of the video?

I'd like to just set the size on the mediaPlayer or MediaElement and not include 20 layout classes like the OSMF examples.

```
private function handle_elementLoaded(e:MediaFactoryEvent):void
{
     mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(e.mediaElement); 
         mediaPlayer.addEventListener(MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent.MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_CHANGE, handle_stateChange);
          }


          private function handle_stateChange(e:MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent):void
          {
               trace("handle_stateChange",e.state);
               if (e.state == MediaPlayerState.READY)
                      {
                    addChild(mediaPlayer.displayObject);
                      } 
          }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is relatively simple.  We've introduced the MediaPlayerSprite to take care of most of the headache for you:

public function MediaPlayerSpriteSample()
{

//Neccesary to prevent the MPS from scaling via ScaleX and ScaleY.

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

// Create the container class that displays the media.

mps = new MediaPlayerSprite();

addChild(mps);

stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResize);

mps.resource = new URLResource(REMOTE_AKAMAI_STREAM);

//Update the MPS to the initial size.

onResize();

}

private function onResize(event:Event = null):void

{

mps.width = stage.stageWidth;

mps.height = stage.stageHeight;

}